# how to get specific elements from a const boost::multi_array

Tags: c++, boost, multidimensional-array, boost-multi-array

I would like to know how to read elements from a **const boost::multi_array** object.
Indeed to my knowledge I can't use the operator [] because it's also used to assignement.

I have a 3-D dimentional array. So how does one get the element **myArray[i][j][k]** when myArray is const.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to [juanchopanza's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/661519/juanchopanza) answer you can also access elements via an index array build from a boost::array.

```
typedef boost::multi_array<double,3>::index tIndex;
typedef boost::array<tIndex, 3> tIndexArray;

tIndexArray index = {{ 1,2,3 }};
const double x = myArray( index );
```

Would give you the element `myArray[1][2][3]`. In case you are writing dimension-independent code this notation might be more useful than explicitly using the [] operator.

Answer (score 2):

You can read them by value or by const reference. Assuming your array holds elements of type T:

```
T x = myArray[1][2][3];
const T& y = myArray[1][2][3];
```

If you want a pointer to an element of the multi_array, then the pointer needs to be const:

```
const T* y = &myArray[1][2][3];
```

Comment: In fact I am trying to add the element in an stl vector and I got a compilation error when I used the [] operator.   error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const _Tp&) [with _Tp = <T*, _Alloc = std::allocator<T*>]’

Comment: @user1287983 could you add the vector declaration, the myArray declaration, and the line where you try to fill the vector?

Comment: vector<T*> my_vector <br/> const boost::multi_array<T, 3> * my_array <br/> my_vector.push_back(& (*my_array)[i][j][k])

Comment: @user1287983 in this case you would need std::vector<const T*>.

Comment: @tuxworker I'm glad it helped. If you found the answers useful, you can up-vote them. This also applies to the answer you accepted.